# Rails 3 model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making a simple BBS system with ruby on rails3.

3 main modesl are Members/Categories/Articles.

Article belongs to Members/Categories, (member_id/category_id columns in db table)
and each member/category 'has_many' articles.

When a specific user tries to write an article, I tried it by

```
def new
  @article = current_member.articles.new
end
```

and that automatically filled in a member_id section when an article is created without any form input or anything.

Now, what should I do if I want to automatically fill a category_id column of an article??
I believe every data related jobs should be done within model. However, I am passing in :category value through url

For example,

localhost:3000/articles/qna/new

would mean the article should have an category_id of 2 (assuming category with id=2 has name=qna, also, I did routing jobs that I can successfully get 'qna' from params[:category]).

Should I use

```
 def create
   current_member.articles.build(:category => get_category_id_from_name(params[:category]))
 end
```

? But is it okay? because I believe since models cannot access params variable, controller has to do the above job, and thats not 'rails way'
 I do not want to use nested form, because I do not want user to choose an category when they are writing. Its like, if there is a QnA board, and if user clicked 'write' button, that means user is writing in a QnA board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to add two hidden fields on the form that creates the Article instance, and and assign the values you wish for "category_id" and "member_id" to those hidden fields.

Rails will automatically pull these into the params hash and they will automatically end up in your call to Article.new.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that as well, but what if user uses ex)firefox, the change the hidden readonly-variable to something else??

Comment: If it is still a valid category ID then I don't see the problem. Unless only some members can post to certain categories. Regardless whomever is going to the trouble of changing that hidden form value is obviously expending a lot of effort for no reason. You _could_ check in your controller to see if the category ID for the category in the URL matches the id passed in that hidden input and don't save the article if that isn't the case. Though I'm green enough in RoR to have no idea how to do that.